# Create a Public/Private Key from a PEM Base64Encode string in Haskell

Tags: haskell, rsa

I'm trying to use RSA from cryptonite package to handle encryption and try to create an X509 cert (Data.X509) from a pem encoded cert base64Encoded string so i can access the Public and Private Key. However, i kept getting a "StreamConstructionWrongSize" error. I think i'm missing something here when reading the base64Encoded string in. I included the snippet of the codes. Perhaps, someone can spot the mistake. I'd really appreciate any help.

```
    import Data.String.Conversions (cs)
    import Crypto.Hash (hash, SHA256(..), Digest)
    import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
    import Data.Text.Encoding (encodeUtf8)
    import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
    import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)
    import Data.ByteArray.Encoding (convertToBase, Base (Base64))
    import Data.X509 

    main :: IO ()
    main = do 
      let certBS = encodeUtf8 "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"
          cert = decodeSignedCertificate certBS
      case cert of 
          Left st -> putStrLn $ "Error reading cert: " ++ st 
          Right scrt -> do 
            let crt = getCertificate scrt 
            putStrLn $ show crt
```

Comment: When you say "create the ... key from a ... string" you are basically saying you want to decode a value.  How much Haskell do you know?  You can decode the base64 to a bytestring using packages like `base64-bytestring`, decode the bytestring via `binary` or `cereal`, and construct your key using one of cryptonite's constructors such as [PrivateKey](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite-0.25/docs/Crypto-PubKey-RSA.html#t:PrivateKey).  Why do you have to do so much yourself? Because, so far as you've said, you don't have a standard encoding. PEM decoding exists if that's your format.

Comment: I'm very new to haskell. The base64Encoded string representation of a certificate (public or private) is what i was referring to. I think what i'm looking for is a way to create the X509 cert (from Data.X509) from the cert's base64Encoded string and then i can access the Public and Private key from there.
The Data.X509 has ecodeSignedCertificate that will take in a ByteString but it keeps failing with "StreamConstructionWrongSize" error. I'm still searching for the right way to do to this. I updated my question to include the code snippet. Perhaps, you guys can help me spot the problem. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated: I found the solution to my question. Hope this helps other who has the same problem

```
           {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

            module Main where

            import Data.String.Conversions (cs)
            import Crypto.Hash (hash, SHA256(..), Digest)
            import qualified Data.ByteString  as BS (ByteString, readFile)
            import Data.Text.Encoding (encodeUtf8)
            import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO
            import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)
            import Data.ByteArray.Encoding (convertToBase, Base (Base64))
            import Data.List (head)
            import Data.Text (Text(..))
            ----- Read file import
            import Data.Monoid ((<>))
            import Control.Applicative
            import Data.ASN1.Types 
            import Data.ASN1.BinaryEncoding
            import Data.ASN1.Encoding
            import Data.Maybe
            import qualified Data.X509 as X509
            import           Data.X509.Memory (pemToKey)
            import Data.PEM (pemParseLBS, pemParseBS, pemWriteBS, pemContent, pemName, PEM)
            import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L


            -------------------------


            main :: IO ()
            main = do 
            --pems  <- readPEMs "./certs/test.pem" -- read from file
            let cert1 = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" ++ "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" ++ "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
            pems <- readPEM cert1
            let certx = X509.decodeSignedObject $ pemContent $ head pems 
            case certx of 
                Left st1 -> putStrLn $ "Error reading cert: " ++ st1 
                Right scrt1 -> do 
                let crt1 = X509.getCertificate scrt1 
                print crt1

            readPEM :: String -> IO [PEM]
            readPEM content = --do
                return $ either error id $ pemParseBS $ cs content 

            readPEMs :: FilePath -> IO [PEM]
            readPEMs filepath = do
                content <- BS.readFile filepath
                return $ either error id $ pemParseBS content
```

Comment: Yep, thanks - that helped.